# How to dynamically create a List Menu using array adapter in Android?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I am creating a list menu which needs to change everytime I call the class where I created it. But once created, it remains the same. I tried using adapter.clear() but it doesnt work too. Can somebody please SUGGEST EDITS to the code below.

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 /*   for( int i = 0; i< j ; i++) {
        classes[i] = Http.sarr[i];
        ref[i] = Http.name[i];
    }*/
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Http.sarr);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = Http.name[position];
    String link = "http://www.codeforces.com/problemset/problem/";
    link = link.concat(cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(link));
    startActivity(ourIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    //finish();
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Class ourClass = null;
    try {
        ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.avinash.myapplication.Mainapp");
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is your problem exactly? when you are clicking on any item of your menu, you are asking for Url to be opened in a browser. So you will be navigated away from `Menu` activity and `onPause()` would be called. But here again you are starting a new `Activity` using `reflection` and it would basically conflict and probably crash. Please tell us more about your design flow.